# Combine leaflet-tilelayer-mask and Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter plugins

Tags: leaflet, javascript, leaflet-plugins

I am trying to color my [tileLayer mask](https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-mask) differently and I found the [colorFilter](https://github.com/xtk93x/Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter) plugin. I can't seem to figure how to use the color filter tile created in my mask tileLayer.

```
let map = L.map("map", {
  zoom: 16,
  center: [35.9734, 117.7926]
});

let sampleFilter = [
  'bright:85%',
  'hue:83deg',
  'saturate:97%'
];

// background layer -- color filter plugin
let myTileLayer = L.tileLayer.colorFilter('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
  attribution: '',
  filter: sampleFilter,
}).addTo(map);
    
// mask layer -- tileLayer mask plugin
let mask = L.tileLayer.mask('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
   maskSize: 512,
   maxZoom: 18,
   maxNativeZoom: 17
 }).addTo(map);
    
mask.setCenter(e.containerPoint);
```

Comment: If you look at the plugin docs https://github.com/xtk93x/Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter, you are missing `filter` option, where you specify your color filter.

Comment: The filter option was missed in error; I will correct that. But my main question is how to use the "myTileLayer" in "mask".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but there is no out-of-the-box solution. You have to create your own plugin, which combines `leaflet-tilelayer-mask` and `Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter` plugins.

New plugin, let's name it `L.TileLayer.ColorFilterMask`, is created by extending  `L.TileLayer.ColorFilter` instead of `L.TileLayer` when creating new mask plugin.

Code in `leaflet-tilelayer-mask.js` has to be modified in three places. First initial definition line:

```
L.TileLayer.ColorFilterMask = L.TileLayer.ColorFilter.extend({
```

Then we insert color filter at the end of `_initContainer` method:

```
_initContainer: function() {
  .
  .
  .
  this._container.style.filter = this.colorFilter();
},
```

Then at the end layer creation function is modified:

```
L.tileLayer.colorFilterMask = function(url, options) {
  return new L.TileLayer.ColorFilterMask(url, options);
};
```

When linking plugin modules, first `leaflet-tilelayer-colorfilter.js` has to be linked and then newly created `leaflet-tilelayer-mask.js`.

Colored mask layer is then created simply by:

```
let sampleFilter = [
  'bright:85%',
  'hue:83deg',
  'saturate:97%'
];

    
let coloredMask = L.tileLayer.colorFilterMask('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
  maskSize: 512,
  filter: sampleFilter,
  maxZoom: 18,
  maxNativeZoom: 17
}).addTo(map);
```

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/w0z1t8L6/

**EDIT**: After some more testing this solution seems to be working only in Firefox. Reason for this is that mask plugin does not create it's masked layer in `<div>` element but in `<svg>` element that contains `<image>` links to layer tiles. Color filter is then applied to this layer through `style` attribute, for example `style="filter: brightness(85%) hue-rotate(83deg) saturate(97%);"`. This kind of filter works for `<svg>` with embedded images only in Firefox. I tried also with `-webkit-filter`, but it didn't help.

This problem can be solved with a little dirty trick of creating separate map pane for masked layer and then instead of applying color filter through combined mask and color filter plugin, just using mask plugin and then applying color filter through map pane style.

So there is no need to use color filter plugin, just mask plugin and setting color filter on map pane element style:

```
let myPane = map.createPane('my-pane');
myPane.style.filter = 'brightness(85%) hue-rotate(83deg) saturate(97%)';

let mask = L.tileLayer.mask('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
  maskSize: 512,
  maxZoom: 18,
  maxNativeZoom: 17,
  pane: 'my-pane'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Awesome. Let me give it a try and revert.

Comment: I have tried all that you hinted on including ensuring that on loading my scripts in *.html file that the colorfilter plugin file comes first before the newly created but doesn't still work.

I noticed that it should be necessary to pass the filter option in thee options of the mask, that is in the newly created plugin.

`options: {
            maskUrl: defaultMaskUrl,
            maskSize: 512
        },
`

Comment: I added working JSFiddle. Code for both plugins is included in the code.

Comment: Yup, I just ran it and which is structured just like mine and I don't see the effects of the filter properties set on the mask. Mask is as plain as the default mask plugin style.

Comment: Are you sure? I changed filter's `hue`, have a look now.

Comment: Yup, I am sure. Same situation. Trying to attach a screenshot now

EDIT: Link [here](https://ibb.co/yQ67GDG)

Comment: This is getting interesting. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome. If I'll have time I'll have a look what could be the reason.

Comment: Ah, I see. I use Chrome. Will try to debug what the situation is after trying it on Firefox.

Comment: See my new solution.

Comment: Thank you, TomazicM. Yeah, filter isn't available on SVG for [Chrome](developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/…) Sad! But the pane does it real good. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109629/discussion-between-b-jugger-and-tomazicm).